# Read CSV files with known and unknown columns in java

Tags: java, spring, csv, opencsv

I'm wondering if there is a way to read csv files with known and unknown columns.

For example, the column in the first csv file is:
**id, firstname, lastname, city, country** the unknown columns are city and country

the second csv file is:

**id, firstname, lastname, phone number** the unknown column is phone number

The Object that I want to parse into is:

```
public class Person {

    Long id;
    String firstname;
    String lastname;

    Map<String,String> additionalInfo;

}
```

The additionalInfo map will contain as keys the 'unknown' columns and the values will be the row value in that column.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried with `opencsv`?

Comment: I did, but I didn't see an option that handles unknown columns

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OpenCSV allows you to do something similar to this using `@CsvBindAndJoinByName` annotation. Taken from [the docs](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/#reading_into_beans):

```
public class Demonstration {

   @CsvBindByName(column = "index")
   private String index;

   @CsvBindAndJoinByName(column = ".*", elementType = String.class)
   private MultiValuedMap<String, String> theRest;

   // Getters and setters go here
}
```

The same docs mention a caveat: you have to be careful not to have overlapping patterns if you have multiple `@CsvBindAndJoinByName`, otherwise the result is undefined.

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out and let you know

Answer (score 1):

Had the same situation, wanted to access the unknown column from a CSV file. Here is the solution

```
public class CSVFileDTO 
{
    @CsvBindByName
    private String name;

    @CsvBindAndJoinByName(column = ".*", elementType = String.class)
    private MultiValuedMap<String, String> theRest;
}
```

Way to access theRest column

```
    CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("/tmp/data.csv")));
    List<CSVFileDTO> resultData = new CsvToBeanBuilder(csvReader)
            .withType(CSVFileDTO.class)
            .build()
            .parse();

    MultiValuedMap<String, String> multivaluedMap = resultData.get(0).getTheRest();
    for(Map.Entry<String, String> ent : multivaluedMap.entries())
    {
        System.out.println( ent.getKey() + " : " + ent.getValue() );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check feature 9 of this https://github.com/ozlerhakan/poiji API for reading excel files.

```
public class MusicTrack {

@ExcelCellName("ID")
private String employeeId;

@ExcelCellName("AUTHOR")
private String author;

@ExcelCellName("NAME")
private String name;

@ExcelUnknownCells
private Map<String, String> unknownCells;}
```